# Генерация как можно более постоянного траффика

Tags: python, c, сеть, udp

как сгенерировать постоянный исходящий UDP траффик?

```
def load_generator():
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
while (True):
    delay = (PACKET_SIZE * 8.) / (BITRATE * 1000 )
    sleep(delay)
    bytes = bytearray(PACKET_SIZE)
    sock.sendto(bytes, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        load_generator()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Stopped by Key"
```

В коде выше есть две проблемы:

1) sleep() не имеет той точности, которая мне нужна

2) вытекает из предыдущего - чем больший битрейт нужно гененировать, тем меньше нужно ждать, тем больше ошибка в точности ожидания

3) sendto блокирующий и то же занимает время, поэтому ошибка накапливается

Как вообще правильно реализуют такую генерацию если нужна точность, а скачки битрейта нужно свести к минимуму?

P.S. iperf тоже не подходит т.к. у него тоже наблюдаются "скачки" битрейта

Comment: Обычно проблема sleep() решается тем, что вы планируете время пробуждения как функцию от шага (т.е. считаете очередной аргумент sleep() от времени в точке старта), а не передаете в sleep() фиксированное время

Comment: скачки будут получаться в любом случае изза того что трафик планирует ос

Comment: Ядрёным pktgen'ом, может быть? https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/pktgen.txt

Comment: В соверменных не-РВ операционных системах с вытесняющей многозадачностью вы никогда не добьётесь точности. Разве что если точность для вас на самом деле не настолько важна - какая именно точность вам нужна-то?

Comment: @avp, ну, предположим, на каждой итерации будет значение для sleep перессчитано... так точность самой sleep то не изменится, она все равно будет давать недетерминированность, разве нет?

Comment: @andreymal, ну, скажем, чтобы с точностью до секунды не более 1 процента чтобы траффик прыгал

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev, у меня ситуация лишь между хостом и виртуалкой на этом хосте... а pktgen используется для сетевого оборудования, насколько понял

Comment: Фраза "с точностью до секунды" непонятна. Вам нужна задержка в одну секунду и вас устроит разброс задержки от 0.990 до 1.010 секунд? Или не более 1 процента от чего?

Comment: Если вам нужно поддерживать примерно постоянный битрейт передаваемого трафика, то может быть достаточно просто пересчитывать delay с учётом возникающих погрешностей

Comment: Например, что-то вроде этого: https://pastebin.com/iQXaWC94 — на моём компьютере даёт более-менее стабильный битрейт при скорости до тысячи пакетов в секуду, а если больше, то начинает немного не успевать

Comment: @andreymal, Тот же iperf3 варьирует битрейт от заданного на 10% рандомно... мне вот хотелось чтобы не 10%, а 1%
ваше решение, кстати, более-менее подходит

Answer (score 2):

Прежде всего, хочу сказать, что тестирование пропускной способности должно выполняться в соответствии с RFC 2544 и Y.1564.

> sleep() не имеет той точности, которая мне нужна

Можно использовать  *nanosleep* - остановка работы процесса с более точным указанием периода. Но лучше всё-таки использовать не засыпание на некий интервал, а переиодические прерывания по таймеру. Они происходят в **заданное** время. Используйте

```
getitimer, setitimer - считывает или устанавливает значение таймера интервалов

ОПИСАНИЕ
       Данные  системные  вызовы  предоставляют  доступ  к  интервальным  таймерам,  то есть таймерам, у которых
       изначально истекает срок в будущем, и (необязательно) с регулярными интервалами после.  Когда  у  таймера
       истекает  срок,  вызвавшему процессу отправляется сигнал и таймер перезапускается с задаваемым интервалом
       (если интервал не равен нулю).
```

> Как вообще правильно реализуют такую генерацию

С помощью аппаратных генераторов трафика. Например  *SunSet* или вот таких: http://spirent.pr-group.ru/%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-spirent/

> iperf тоже не подходит

Есть ещё:

- iperf3
- NetPerf
- Ostinato
- PackEth
- Nping
- Netcps
- Netspeed
- DU Meter

Хотя, после долгих поисков, я сам плюнул и написал свой :-) Но в нём использовалось аж два аппаратных генератора трафика IKO-1G российского производства.

Comment: спасибо за информацию, даже не знал про это